# What is "Internal call method with non_NULL RVA. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)" when I try to connect to SQL Server using Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have just instaled SQL Server and I'm trying to connect using Management Studio, but I'm getting the following error:

===================================

`Cannot connect to FORTEORANGE.`

===================================

`Internal call method with non_NULL RVA. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)`

---

`Program Location:`

```
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetServerObject()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.get_Information()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.CheckAndEnableSmoXps(SqlConnection connection, Boolean smoXpsEnabled)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.CheckDacAndSmo(SqlConnection sqlConnection)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

Comment: What version are you using of SQL Server and SSMS?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 and Management Studio 2012

Comment: I would follow advise in the answer and re-install the SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.  Did some searching on google.

RVA = relative virtual address and NON NULL means it was called with some invalid memory location.

Looking farther, I find this post on issues with SSMS when a DLL goes bad.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8d77f72d-a702-49a9-9f7c-c4b43fa72ea7/logon-problem-with-ms-sql-2005-management-studio

Do you have another machine to try the connection.  If it works on that machine, there is something wrong with you machine.

Check the hard disk (check disk).

Optionally re-install SSMS to fix the issue.  The user in this post did a nuke and load of the laptop.